# Creating single object DataFrame for predictions

Tags: spark-streaming

once I got my classification models trained, I'd like them to use in my web application to make classification predictions on the data that has been collected for a given session. 
That is:
1) I have some session data structure that I need to map to a DataFrame row 
2) feed tha DataFrame row into my ML model to predict the classification
3) use the prediction with the origination session to show it to the user in front of the browser.

The examples to create a DataFrame as input to a Spark pipeline that I've seen so far create it from a data source like a file. Now it seems a bit unwieldy to first create a single POJO or JsonNode, serialize it to file containing just on record and then use that file to create the DataFrame to feed the model.
Writing this I also get the feeling that it might not be a great idea to create and tear down the ML pipeline for each request, which seems to follow from this approach.

So maybe I should better think "Spark Streaming"?

Feed the mapped session data into some kind of message queue and feed that into my Spark pipeline? What kind of "stream" would be appropriate here?

I read somewhere that Spark streaming consumes the stream in micro batches and not record by record - that implies some delay until enough records have been collected to fill up the micro batch (or some preconfigured delay to wait until the micro batch is considered to be "full enough"). What does that mean for the responsiveness of the web application? Can I trigger the micro batches like every 100 milliseconds?

I would appreciate if someone could point me in the right direction.
Maybe Spark is not a good fit here and I should switch to Apache Flink?

Thanks in advance, Bernd

Comment: No, you don't need Spark Streaming (although you *could* implement something with it as well). What you need is to serve your model. If you are doing it in Spark, it's an application that keeps a live Spark Session. It accepts requests from your web app and passes it to Spark for scoring. You will typically build your single-record dataframe from the request (not from a file!) and pass it to the SparkML `transformer` that you got from training your model. Then you respond to your client with the result.

Answer (score 0):

> Ok, by now I have found some ways to solve my problem, maybe that
>   helps someone else:
>
> #### Use a Sequence containing one tuple and name the columns separately
>
> ```
> val df= spark.createDataFrame(
>   Seq("val1", "val2")
> ).toDF("label1", "label2")
> ```
>
> #### Using a JSON-String
>
> ```
> val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext 
> val jsonData= """{ "label1": "val1", "label2": "val2" }"""    
> val rdd= sparkSession.sparkContext.parallelize(Seq(jsonData))
> val df= sqlContext.read.json(rdd)
> ```
>
> #### NOT Working: create from Sequence case class Objects:
>
> ```
> val sqlContext = sparkSession.sqlContext 
> import sqlContext.implicits._
>
> val myData= Seq(Feat("value1", "value2"))
> val ds: Dataset[Feat]= myData.toDS()
> ds.show(10, false)
> ```
>
> This compiles ok, but yields an Exception at runtime:
>
> ```
>  [error] a.a.OneForOneStrategy - java.lang.RuntimeException:
> Error while encoding:  java.lang.ClassCastException:
> es.core.recommender.Feat cannot be cast to es.core.recommender.Feat
> ```
>
> I'd love to include more of the stacktrace, but this glorious editor
>   won't let me...
>
> It would be nice to know why this alternative did not work...